# webpack babel how to copy transpiled file if i don't use import/require

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have a file in my project called `test.js`

I don't import/require it anywhere which means my webpack won't call `babel-loader` for that js file.

**Question: what I want is to move test.js into /dist folder, but as a compiled/transpiled. What's the best practice for it?**

**What I tried:** I tried to use a copy-webpack-plugin and use its transform parameters before copying the file, but I can't seem to find the good babel package.

```
{
    from: 'test.js',
        to: '/dist/test.js',
            transform(content, path) {
        //what do I write here? 
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach I could think about is to use several entry points like this:

```
{
    entry: {
        a: "./your-main-stuff",
        b: "./your-single-file",
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].js"
    }
}
```

which will create your `a.js` main bundle and `b.js` file in `__dirname/dist` folder both transpiled provided you used corresponding loader(s).

And from copy-webpack-plugin docs [section](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/):

> webpack-copy-plugin is not designed to copy files generated from the
>   build process; rather, it is to copy files that already exist in the
>   source tree, as part of the build process.

so it seems to be difficult (if possible) making it move transpiled files.

**Update**. If you want to output files into different folders w/o changing your `src` folder, additonal tools needed. For your case (just 1 file) I would write a simple script and add it into package.json script section combined with webpack call like:

```
"scripts": {
     "dev": "webpack && babel path-to-script.js --out-file path-to-script-compiled.js"
 }
```

Comment: the thing is that for entry 'a' i want it to go to the different folder in dist than the entry b. so i need multiple output. is this possible?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili check the discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903246/how-to-create-multiple-output-paths-in-webpack-config

Answer (score 0):

Just like in the previous answer, initially I went with the "scripts" entry in `package.json` that runs `babel`. But for a number of reasons I wanted to use `webpack 5` to do the job. So after failing with `webpack-copy-plugin` and a good amount of digging around I came to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71697364/17821782):

```
let config = {
    entry: [
        glob.sync(srcDir + '/**/*.js') // get all .js files from the source dir
    ],
    output : {
        filename : '[name].rem.js',  // webpack wants to bundle - it can bundle here ;) 
        path: outDir
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'app': appDir
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin({extensions: ['js'], scriptExtensions: /\.rem\.js/}) // for all .js source files that get bundled remove the bundle .rem.js file
    ],
    module: {
        rules:[{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            type: 'asset/resource', // get webpack to take it out instead of bundling
            generator: {
                filename: ({filename}) => filename // return full file name so directory structure is preserved
            },
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    targets: { node: 16 },
                    presets: [
                        ['@babel/preset-env', { modules: 'commonjs' /* transpile import/export */}],
                    ]
                }
            }
        }]
    }
};
// Since the code does not go through the full pipeline and imports are not getting resolved, aliases will remain in the code.
// To resolve them it takes to hack the aliases object into the babel config
config.module.rules[0].use.options.plugins.push(['babel-plugin-webpack-alias-7', {config: {resolve: {alias: config.resolve.alias}}}];
```

And it does a good job but beware that it takes to use the patched versions of the two plugins (unless the patches have been merged already)!